# Cordova SQL - How to execute multiple parameterized insert statements in a single transaction

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I need to execute multiple insert statements into the SQLite database using Cordova. Currently i'm able to achieve this by constructing an array of insert statements, then execute them in the sql transaction block:

```
function populateDB(tx) {

    if(sqls.length > 0) {
        for (var index = 0; index < sqls.length; index++) {
            tx.executeSql(sqls[index]);
        }
    }
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert(err.message);
}

function successCB() {
    alert("insert success!");
}

db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

I learn that i can use parameterized statements with the `tx.executeSql` function but how can i put them into the array so i that i can execute them in a single transaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of SQL statements, then you need to modify it to be a bit more complex so that it also includes your bound params. I'd change to an array of simple objects. Imagine sqls is an array:

sqls[0].sql would be the SQL statement: insert into foo(?,?,?)
sqls[0].params would be an array of params: [2,"foo", 4]

Your code would be modified to simply use each part.